# How to use GROUP BY with UNION in JPQL

Tags: java, jpa, ejb, jpql

I would like generate some data with JPQL for my output in Primefaces `p:dataTable`. I use following query.

```
Query query = this.em.createQuery("SELECT a FROM ProffesorTable a WHERE 
  a.fkProffesorID.name LIKE '"+buffervarQuery+"%' AND a.fkProffesorID.release='TRUE' 
UNION  
(SELECT a FROM ProffesorTable a WHERE a.fkProffesorID.name LIKE '%"+buffervarQuery+"'
  AND a.fkProffesorID.release='TRUE') GROUP BY a.fkProffesorID.name ");

result = query.getResultList();
```

I receive following Exception

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An exception occurred while creating a query in EntityManager: 
>   Exception Description: Internal problem encountered while compiling
>   [SELECT a FROM ProffesorTable a WHERE a.fkProffesorID.name LIKE 'sie%' AND a.fkProffesorID.release='TRUE' 
>   UNION
>   (SELECT a FROM ProffesorTable a WHERE a.fkProffesorID.name LIKE '%sie' AND a.fkProffesorID.name='TRUE') GROUP BY a.fkProffesorID.name ")].
>   [249, 277] The query contains a malformed ending.
>       at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.createQuery(EntityManagerImpl.java:1585)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.createQuery(EntityManagerWrapper.java:456)

Comment: UNIONS are not supported in JPA. Check [this answer][http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17050589/union-in-jpa-query-from-the-same-table] for alternative solutions.

Comment: thank you for your answer. That is not good we didn't use EclipseLink gives there an alternative solution for this question query.

Answer (score 0):

Your simple query can be convert into this one and that supported by jpql as well.

```
SELECT a FROM ProffesorTable a
  WHERE (a.fkProffesorID.name LIKE '"+buffervarQuery+"%' or a.fkProffesorID.name LIKE '%"+buffervarQuery+"')
    AND a.fkProffesorID.release='TRUE' 
  GROUP BY a.fkProffesorID.name
```